# Linq-to-xml to get child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am having trouble identifying how to use linq-to-xml to extract total price and individual prices from the xml below (e.g I want to get the fare price and also sum of all prices). Any help would be much appreciated especially with using the method syntax of linq-to-xml

I use the following code to get the data loaded into an xDocument and work with the xmlResponse object to parse the response.

```
var xmlResponse = from element in xdoc.Descendants()
                              select element;
```

and get data like

```
xmlResponse.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Registration")
```

Below is a subset of thwe xml response :-

```
<StateList>
    <State>
      <SourceJobID>J999999999999</SourceJobID>
      <TargetJobState>Complete</TargetJobState>
      <TargetJobID>11111111</TargetJobID>
      <TargetSystem>TESTSYSTEM</TargetSystem>
      <VehicleDetails>
        <Registration>TESTREGISRATION</Registration>
        <Plate>11111111111</Plate>
        <CO2Rating>160</CO2Rating>
        <Badge>1111111</Badge>
        <Description>TEST DESCRIPTION</Description>
      </VehicleDetails>
      <CompleteDetails>
        <CompletedOn>2015-09-15T13:39:11+01:00</CompletedOn>
        <JobDistance>0</JobDistance>
        <WaitingTime />
        <CO2Usage>0</CO2Usage>
        <ChargeList>
          <Charge>
            <Name>Airport Pickup</Name>
            <Currency>GBP</Currency>
            <Price>0.00</Price>
          </Charge>
          <Charge>
            <Name>Fare</Name>
            <Currency>GBP</Currency>
            <Price>0.00</Price>
          </Charge>
          <Charge>
            <Name>Extra Stops</Name>
            <Currency>GBP</Currency>
            <Price>0.00</Price>
          </Charge>
        </ChargeList>
      </CompleteDetails>
    </State>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have a single state like in your example, you could do something like the following:

```
        decimal fare = decimal.Parse(xml.Descendants("Charge").Single(x => x.Element("Name").Value == "Fare").Element("Price").Value);
        decimal total = xml.Descendants("Charge").Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.Element("Price").Value));
```

Although if you have a series of elements in your list you will have to modify that.

**EDIT:** If, as you say in the comments, you would like to sum only certain charges:

```
        // Valid names of charges to sum.
        string[] names = { "Airport Pickup", "Fare" };
        // Iterate over every state.
        foreach (var state in xml.Descendants("State")) 
        {
            // Get all charge elements in the current state whose names are contained in 'names' - then convert their 'Price' element to decimal and sum them.
            decimal stateTotal = state.Descendants("Charge").Where(x => names.Contains(x.Element("Name").Value)).Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.Element("Price").Value)); 
        }
```

Comment: I needed to change single to first to get first linq query to work. The second query gave me a wonr total when I put a fare of 25.00 and Airport Pickup of 10.00 it brought back a total of 210

Comment: That's because it will sum all charges in all States. If you only want to sum the charges in the first state you can modify the call to:

`decimal total = xml.Descendants("State").First().Descendants("Charge").Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.Element("Price").Value));`

Comment: You could iterate over all states in a manner such as:

`foreach (var state in xml.Descendants("State"))
            {
                decimal stateTotal = state.Descendants("Charge").Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.Element("Price").Value));
            }`

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to sum up some of the charges but not all of them, e.g sum only airport pickup and fare?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(doc.Descendants("Charge").Any())
{
    var FarePrice = doc.Descendants("Charge")
                .Where(x => x.Descendants("Name").First().Value.Equals("Fare")).First().Element("Price").Value;

    var Sum = doc.Descendants("Charge")
                .Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.Descendants("Price").First().Value))
                .Sum();     
    Console.WriteLine("Fare price:{0} Sum:{1}",FarePrice,Sum);
}
```

It returns 35 as sum for 10 and 25 inputs.

Fiddle here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/cuHXBn

Comment: Works nicely. The XML also could have the charges missing. Is there an easy way to check for this and set the FarePrice and Sum to null if that is the case?

Comment: At the moment it brings back "Sequence contains no matching element" if charges are not in the xml doc.

Comment: As with other answer the Sum calculated the wrong total. Brought back 210 for two charges of 25.00 and 10.00

Comment: weird it still gives me the wrong total and i've tried different values

Comment: @macca18 : have you tried the fiddle i added in the answer?